# Finding a string between two strings after a certain word

Tags: python, regex

In the following string:

```
s = '>foo</a> Start >bar</a> >baz</a>'
```

I want to extract the first value that comes between `>` and `</a>` after `start`, which is `bar`.

The following scripts do the job separately, but I don't know how to merge them.

```
regexp = re.compile("Start(.*)$")
output = regexp.search(s).group(1)

output = re.search('>(.*?)</a>', s).group(1)
```

Comment: Use `r"Start[^>]*>(.*?)</a>"` or `r"(?s)Start.*?>([^<]*)</a>"`

Comment: This looks like HTML, is it possible to use a DOM parser instead?

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML?

Comment: Yes, it is a very long HTML, and since I couldn't get Beautifulsoup to work I thought regex is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
r"Start[^>]*>(.*?)</a>"
r"(?s)Start.*?>([^<]*)</a>"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmpdeP/1). Details:

- `Start` - a literal string
- `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `</a>` -  a literal string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EFm3np):

```py
import re
s = '>foo</a> Start >bar</a> >baz</a>'
regexp = re.compile(r"Start.*?>([^<]*)</a>", re.DOTALL)
m = regexp.search(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, Idk what you want to do with this but much simpler is:

```
s = '>foo</a> Start >bar</a> >baz</a>'

print (s.split("</a>")[1].split(">")[-1])
```

Output:

```
bar
```